# htaccess redirect if URL contains a certain string

Tags: .htaccess

How would I write a `.htaccess` redirect rule if the URL contains a certain word?

e.g. if it contains `foobar` then redirect to `index.php`

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} foobar
RewriteRule .* index.php
```

or [some variant thereof](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Works perfectly but just realised instead of rewrite I need it to redirect. Is this possible?

Answer (score 24):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)foobar(.*)$ http://www.example.com/index.php [L,R=301]
```

(No space inside your website)

Comment: How can i get parameters ( eg. $1 )?, RewriteRule ^(.*)foobar(.*)$ /foobar/index.php?q=$1 [L], doesn't get any parameter.

Answer (score 6):

If url contains a certen string, redirect to index.php . You need to match against the **%{REQUEST_URI}** variable to check if the url contains a certen string.

To redirect **example.com/foo/bar** to **/index.php** if the uri contains **bar** anywhere in the uri string  , you can use this :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} bar
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L,R]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/foobar/i$ index.php [NE,L]
```