# "If request" in .htaccess?

Tags: mod-rewrite

I use rewrite condition to redirect website always to www. my code is:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.website\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.website.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I can't found on the internet how can i do request *if in url '.com'* i need it because the website must be also localy accessible.

For example: i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220377/htaccess-redirect-if-url-contains-a-certain-string), but i can't understand how can i implement it with my script.

Comment: Your need isn't quite clear. Please post an example of a domain which should not be rewritten by your rule.  Do you mean to say that you want to only modify the domain of `example.com` while not modifying `localhost`? If so, your current rule should already work.  Or do you want to make your current rule more flexible without hard-coding `example.com` as the domain, but to apply it to any domain (except localhost)?

Comment: I try so: for me is important to redirect domain always domain on www., only online, local it is not needed, because if i use at the moment my script i can work only online, local i get redirect error. Can i do online redirect on www. dynamicly? Without to give everytime website url?

Comment: Oh, I understand. Locally you are seeing the redirect, and you want to avoid that.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski true :), how can i do it?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current `RewriteCond` is correct for applying `www.` to `website.com` if it is not already present. To avoid the `RewriteRule` happening when working on `localhost`, you need an additional `RewriteCond` to check the host.

This is because the condition `!^www\.example\.com$` matches *any* domain *except* `www.example.com`, which includes `localhost`.

```
# Only apply other conditions if not working on localhost
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !localhost [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

You can make it a little more dynamic in case you need to work with multiple domains (`example.com`, `example.org`) and transform each to `www.example.com`, `www.example.org`:

```
# If not on localhost
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !localhost [NC]
# and the domain does not begin www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
# Redirect to apply the www. to HTTP_HOST
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Use caution when testing - your browser may cache old 301 redirects. You may need to change them to `R=302` during testing and clear your browser cache. When you are satisfied it works, change it back to `R=301`.

Comment: I think your script will work, but how have i to replace "localhost " because i have virtual host, localy are url's like "http://test_web_1.local", thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

That RewriteCond should already work for your case, the next rule is processed only if the condition matches, so that rule is not processed for localhost.