# How do you redirect a home page dynamic url to a 404?

Tags: php, dynamic, http-status-code-404, redirect

I have a client who was hacked by a spammer and is now getting hit by many viagra, etc. backlinks to pages that don't exist on her site anymore. I need to send a message to the backlinkers that those pages don't exist anymore in hopes they'll stop their incessant backlinking. Plus I want Google to get the message that the pages don't exist anymore.

How do I redirect urls like this so it responds back with a 404:
http://jenniferdavispainting.com/index.php?option=com_k2&view=itemlist&task=user&id=41292

I can't make anything with JUST index.php redirect to a 404 or the Wordpress site will break but urls with ?option=com would be fine to redirect I THINK, but I don't know.

Also, the backlinkers are mass producing the backlinks to point to every variation of those urls like these:

http://jenniferdavispainting.com/index.php?option=com_k2&view=itemlist&task=user&id=41293 but with the id number changing each time.

Assuming I can redirect those to a 404, how do I write the command in the .htaccess so one command will redirect anything with /index.php?option=com_k2 to a 404.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you not make your index.php return the relevant status if the content wasn't found?

Comment: Please refer [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220377/htaccess-redirect-if-url-contains-a-certain-string]

Comment: Thanks Rowland. The problem is the page is "found." Whichever one of those links you click on always redirects to the home page. Perhaps that's built into Wordpress??? I don't know. I don't want it to do that. I want it to generate a 404. The other concern I have is I don't just want to redirect these to a page called 404, I need to make sure that anyone or anything, particularly the Google bot, gets the message that it's gone.