# redirect url if it contain a specific words using .htaccess and php

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have a URL like , http://localhost/Vishnu/ReDirectionProject/TEST/SubDomain/aa/bb/abc.php?e=1&b=3 when I try to run this URL ie, if it contain any string like "SubDomain" it should redirect me to http://localhost/Vishnu/ReDirectionProject/TEST/somePhpPage.php
and in the `somePhpPage.php` I have a `header()` to redirect to another URL.
So basic problem is when I try to run the URL with string "SubDomain" I need to parse the string after "SubDomain" here it's `aa/bb/abc.php?e=1&b=3`and get this values into `somePhpPage.php` and there I convert/add some predefined URL to it for example : http://localhost/Vishnu/ReDirectionProject/TEST/somePhpPage.php/aa/bb/abc.php?e=1&b=3

So I try to use this .`htaccess` code

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} SubDomain
 RewriteRule .* http://localhost/Vishnu/ReDirectionProject/TEST/UrlRedirect.php [L,R=301]
```

it works fine except when the URL does not have the query like `abc.php`
if it contain any query like `abc.php?e=1&b=3` it shows 
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error

EDIT :

PHP Page :

```
  function urlRedirection() {
    $link       = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
    $pageName       = basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
    $rmvPath        = trim(strip_tags(substr($link,strpos($link,$pageName))));  
    if (strrpos($rmvPath,"?")) {
        $rmvPath        = substr($rmvPath,0,strrpos($rmvPath,"?")); 
    }
    $cnvFolders     = explode("/",$rmvPath);
    $folderIndex    = 0 ;
    $allwdExtns     = array(".php",".html",".asp",".jsp");
    for ($i=0;$i<count($cnvFolders);$i++) {
        if (strpos($cnvFolders[$i],".")) {
            $allwdExtChk    = substr($cnvFolders[$i],strpos($cnvFolders[$i],"."));
            if (in_array($allwdExtChk,$allwdExtns)) {
                $phpFiles[] = $cnvFolders[$i];  
            }
        }
        if (strpos($cnvFolders[$i],".")) {
            $cnvFolders[$i]     = "";   
        }
    }
    $lastFile   = count($phpFiles)-1; 
    $crtFolder  = implode("/",$cnvFolders) . "<br>";
    $crtFolder  = trim(strip_tags($crtFolder),"/");
    if (!file_exists($crtFolder)) {
        mkdir( $crtFolder, 0777, true );
    }
    $crtFile    = fopen("$crtFolder/$phpFiles[$lastFile]", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");

    $parameters = substr($link,strpos($link,"?")+strlen("?"));
    $cnvParamts = explode("&",$parameters);
    foreach ($cnvParamts as $paramWriting) {
        $paramWriting   = '$'.$paramWriting .';';
        $writeFile      = fwrite($crtFile,$paramWriting);   
    }

    $subdomainSelect    = substr($link,strpos($link,"date.")+strlen("date."));
    $curDate    = date('Y-m-d');
    $date = new DateTime($curDate);
    $date->modify('+1 day');
    $tommorrow  = $date->format('Y-m-d');
    $date->modify('+1 day');
    $dayAfterTommorrow  = $date->format('Y-m-d');
    $chkInTime          = substr($subdomainSelect,strpos($subdomainSelect,"checkin")+strlen("checkin"));
    if (strpos($chkInTime,"&")) {
        $chkInTime          = substr($chkInTime,0,strpos($chkInTime,"&"));
    }
    $chkInTime          = trim(strip_tags($chkInTime),"=");
    $chkOutTime = substr($link,strpos($link,"checkout")+strlen("checkout"));
    if (strpos($chkOutTime,"&")) {
        $chkOutTime = substr($chkOutTime,0,strpos($chkOutTime,"&"));
    }
    $chkOutTime = trim(strip_tags($chkOutTime),"=");
    if (strpos($subdomainSelect,"checkin")) {
        $subdomainSelect    = str_replace($chkInTime,$tommorrow,$subdomainSelect);      
    } else {
        $subdomainSelect    = $subdomainSelect."&checkin=$tommorrow";   
    }
    if (strpos($subdomainSelect,"checkout")) {
        $subdomainSelect    = str_replace($chkOutTime,$dayAfterTommorrow,$subdomainSelect);
    } else {
        $subdomainSelect    = $subdomainSelect."&checkout=$dayAfterTommorrow";
    }
    $subdomainSelect    = trim($subdomainSelect,"//");
    $subdomainSelect    = "http://".$subdomainSelect;
    if ($subdomainSelect) { 
        header("location:$subdomainSelect");
    }
}
urlRedirection();
```

Comment: Try this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3220390/3202287)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /TEST/SubDomain/(\S+)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /Vishnu/ReDirectionProject/TEST/UrlRedirect.php/%1 [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: Thanks , but it show me ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error

Comment: I have clear the history and there is nothing other than your given code in my .htaccess file still the same error

Comment: this is my path , D:\xamp\htdocs\Vishnu\ReDirectionProject\TEST\SubDomain\.htaccess

Comment: It works on mine as well, please give us your entire htaccess file. I bet something else is causing your problem

Comment: Here is my full path , D:\xamp\htdocs\Vishnu\ReDirectionProject\TEST\SubDomain  under the SubDomain folder I am having my .htaccess file . I have only one .htaccess file in my "ReDirectionProject" folder . but some other .htaccess file in "Vishnu" folder . Excuse me for my English

Comment: @anubhava , The mistake was from my custom php files finally it solved and great thanks

Comment: 1 for your valuable time

Answer (score 1):

This should work, the QSA flag will attach the original querystring to the rewritten url and you can specific the path that should redirect inside the `RewriteCond` line

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)SubDomain\/aa\/bb\/abc.php(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /Vishnu/ReDirectionProject/TEST/somePhpPage.php [L,R=301,QSA]
```

Comment: @VishnuRNair can you post more of your htaccess file? you might have something else going on causing a redirect loop

Comment: This code does not redirect me to the page I needed but it show me a file not found error .

Comment: @VishnuRNair if you rename the directory "TEST" to something different like "TEST1" does that fix your problem? I believe apache will remove this during rewrites if it precedes the regex modifier

Comment: @VishnuRNair I updated my answer, see if that works for you

Comment: anubhava's code work fine but the only problem is that the ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error

Comment: Should I Edit my question with the somePhpPage.php page

Comment: The more info you can give us, the better we'll be able to help you

Comment: @ iam-decoder , Thanks and finally it get solved and the mistake was from my php part . once again thank you for your time and effort