# Redirecting all URLs containing a word to a URL by htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

Want redirecting all URLs containing `Bolivia` to www.example.com/US/, e.g:

```
www.example.com/search.php?country=Bolivia&Select=Ingeni&&Location=Hiller
```

redirect to
www.example.com/US/

Tried this, not work:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+?&)?Bolivia[^&]*(?:&(.*))?$
RewriteRule ^ "/US/"
```

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/3220390/864233

Comment: tried this not work: RewriteRule ^(.*)Bolivia(.*)$ http://www.example.com/US/ [L,R=301]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the solution:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} Bolivia 
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com/US/? [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} Bolivia
Redirect 301 / http://example.com/us/
```

Comment: loop redirect to something like: example.com/us/us/us/us/us/us/us/us/us/us/us/us/us/us/us/us/us/us/us/us/us/searh.php

Comment: you are Supposed to change the example.com to your site name

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /search\.php\?country=Bolivia&Select=([^&]+)&&?Location=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /US/? [L,R]
```

Comment: I'm not looking for this exact example but all URL that contain 'Bolivia'