# How to properly configure .htaccess (rewrite)

Tags: .htaccess

This is my first question here and all I can say is that I am really glad to be part of this community.

Now, as part of the question. I have a small problem configuring my htaccess properly, I have tried numerous lines of code which I have found here and there, trying my best to come close to something relevant or close to what I want, but no matter what.. I was failing. I tried redirect, redirect 301, both with and without full links, rewrite url with and without extension in the end but nothing happened.

So, what's my question exactly.

I have a form which when somebody clicks on the "send" button, the form tries to launch a file. It produces the following link:

```
domain.com/api/services/notification/send.php?accept=json&contentType=json&appUrl=http://domain.com
```

Although, while I have `send.php` under `api/services/notification/` it's not called at all because there's no extension when the form produces the link, resulting in a 404 error. So, I tried several times to make `.htaccess` to redirect send into `send.php` but every time I was facing a huge fail. My assumption is; because it's within other letters/words. Mainly, I want `.htaccess` to "replace" `send` into `send.php` without affecting the rest of the URL, using `mod_rewrite`.

Any insights on this? The last code which I hoped that would work but didn't at all, was this one:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^send?([^/]+) /send.php?accept=json&contentType=json&appUrl=http://domain.com [NC]
```

Comment: have you enabled mod_rewrite?? if not and you are on linux check here on how to do it https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mod_rewrite-for-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Yes, it's enabled. mod_rewrite is working :)

Comment: try here then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220377/htaccess-redirect-if-url-contains-a-certain-string

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: check .htaccess works -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234289/how-to-debug-htaccess-rewriterule-not-working

Answer (score 1):

You can try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/api/services/notification/send$ /api/services/notification/send.php [L]
```